# WPF/Silverlight - Prism - Resources for beginners

Tags: .net, wpf, silverlight, architecture, prism

**Official Websites**

- [Composite Application Guidance for WPF and Silverlight](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd458809.aspx)
- [patterns & practices: Composite WPF and Silverlight](http://compositewpf.codeplex.com/)

**Articles**

- [Composite Web Apps With Prism](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd943055.aspx)

**Podcasts**

- [PRISM for Silverlight - Connected Show](http://www.connectedshow.com/default.aspx?Episode=10)

**Videocasts**

- [SlickThought.Net - Jeff Brand](http://www.slickthought.net/category/WPF-Composite-App.aspx)

**dnrTV**

- [Brian Noyes on Prism](http://www.dnrtv.com/default.aspx?showNum=124)
- [Brian Noyes on Prism Events and Commands](http://www.dnrtv.com/default.aspx?showNum=132)

**Channel 9**

- [What is Prism v2?](http://channel9.msdn.com/posts/akMSFT/What-is-Prism-v2/)
- [When to use Prism for Silverlight or WPF apps podcast](http://channel9.msdn.com/posts/ContinuumNews/When-to-use-Prism-for-Silverlight-or-WPF-apps-podcast/)
- [Prism v2 - Composite Application Guidance for WPF and Silverlight](http://channel9.msdn.com/shows/Continuum/Prismv2/)
- [1/4 - Creating a shell and modules](http://channel9.msdn.com/posts/akMSFT/Creating-a-modular-application-using-Prism-V2-Part-1-of-4--Creating-a-shell-and-modules/)
- [2/4 - Visual Composition](http://channel9.msdn.com/posts/akMSFT/Creating-a-modular-application-using-Prism-V2-Screencast-24--Visual-Composition/)
- [3/4 - Implementing views and services](http://channel9.msdn.com/posts/akMSFT/Creating-a-modular-application-using-Prism-V2-Screencast-34--Implementing-views-and-services/)
- [4/4 - Decoupled Communication](http://channel9.msdn.com/posts/akMSFT/Creating-a-modular-application-using-Prism-v2-Screencast-44--Decoupled-Communication/)

---

**Have you some recommendation to other resources for Prism?**

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I've been creating Prism (Silverlight slant but most applies to WPF as well) resources:

**If you have 5 minutes**: [10 Things to Know About Prism](http://www.sparklingclient.com/prism-silverlight/)

**If you have 20 minutes**: [Prism Basics Video](http://development-guides.silverbaylabs.org/Video/Silverlight-Prism)

**videos**

[Intro to Silverlight Prism](http://development-guides.silverbaylabs.org/Video/Silverlight-Prism)

[Testing/Module Catalog/Unity](http://development-guides.silverbaylabs.org/Video/Modularity-in-Prism)

[Regions (including Region Scope, Region Adapter and Region Context)](http://development-guides.silverbaylabs.org/Video/Prism-Regions)

[Commanding (including creating new commands)](http://development-guides.silverbaylabs.org/Video/Prism-Commands)

[Eventing](http://www.sparklingclient.com/prism-in-silverlight/)

**podcast interviews with the Prism Team**

[What is Prism](http://www.sparklingclient.com/prism-in-silverlight/)

[Modularity in Prism](http://www.sparklingclient.com/modularity-in-prism/)

[When to use Prism](http://www.sparklingclient.com/when-to-use-prism/)

[View or Presenter First?](http://www.sparklingclient.com/which-comes-first-the-view-or-the-viewmodel/)

[Commanding](http://www.sparklingclient.com/commanding-in-prism/)

[Event Aggregator](http://www.sparklingclient.com/prisms-event-aggregator/)

**blog posts**

[10 Things to Know about Silverlight Prism (overview of all resources)](http://www.sparklingclient.com/prism-silverlight/)

[Downloading and Building Prism](http://www.sparklingclient.com/downloading-and-building-prism/)

Answer (score 0):

I particularly like Brian Lagunas' videos. He has recently been keeping Prism up to date and his videos are mostly in-sync with the latest Prism updates.

[brianlagunas.com/category/prism/](https://brianlagunas.com/category/prism/)

[Brian Lagunas YouTube Channel](https://www.youtube.com/brianlagunas)

[GitHub Prism Library](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism)